# Why can I not use auto in a recursive lambda function?

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda

This is code inside my `mergeSort` method,

```
    std::function<void(std::vector<T>*)> mergeSortRange = [&](std::vector<T>* array) -> void {
        int length = (int) array->size();
        if (length < 2)
            return;
        std::vector<T>* leftArr = new std::vector<T>(array->begin(), array->begin() + length / 2);
        std::vector<T>* rightArr = new std::vector<T>(array->begin() + length / 2, array->end());
        mergeSortRange(leftArr);
        mergeSortRange(rightArr);
        mergeTwoSortedArrrays(leftArr, rightArr, array);
        delete leftArr;
        delete rightArr;
    };
```

I could have substituted the first line with:

`auto mergeSortRange = [&](std::vector<T>* array) -> void` , and I'd expect it to work fine (excuse my ignorance).

But instead the compiler complains saying:

> Variable 'mergeSortRange' declared with 'auto' cannot appear in its
>   own initializer.

I have specified both the parameters and the return type. Could somebody throw some light on this?

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: because variable "mergeSortRange" gets its type only at the end of the statement, and you are trying to use it before

Comment: What is a "type"? Is it different from return type?

Comment: Unrelated but why use new to allocate the vectors?

Comment: Note that the lambda function's type is *not* `std::function<void(std::vector<T>*)>` – it has a unique, unnameable type.

Comment: This is a similar situation to `auto i = i;`.

Comment: @user2717954 Because I wanted it to be a vector pointer?

Comment: There is no reason to use `new` just to get pointers. First you should be using references here and secondly you can get a pointer to `std::vector<T> a;` with `&a`.

Answer (score -1):

Your program is ill-formed because as Riad says, you are trying to call the function before the type is deduced:

> [dcl.spec.auto/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#10) If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed. Once a non-discarded return statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements.